# Easiest place to find loot Goliaths and make god-liaths

Tags: borderlands-2

I've looked at a lot of places all over the place, like Sanctuarys hole and had no luck, except for two Goliaths.  I am a level 18 assassin, mainly use snipers, shotguns, and revolvers on occasion I use SMGs.

Comment: i remember seeing some in frostburn canyon and also on the slab king's initiation quest.

Answer (score 10):

Loot Goliaths are just rare forms of the standard Goliaths, so the best place to farm them is wherever you find Goliaths.  Tundra Express has several large bandit encampments, and I tend to find them and the slot machine Goliaths regularly on this particular map.  (In fact, I found one just last night right outside Tiny Tina's...)

Since they're rare, you're not going to see them often.  I don't think they're particularly good for farming loot compared to other methods, given their rarity.

Farming a God-Liath requires that you have a somewhat powerful Goliath, and enough enemies to level him completely up.

Good spots to farm these guys balance three factors:

- If the Goliath is too weak, he'll lose to the enemies
- If there aren't enough enemy spawns, he won't level up enough
- If he's too tough, you won't be able to kill him after he maxes out

Again, there are a lot of bandits in Tundra Express.  I don't like Frostburn Canyon for this because the flamethrower nomads tend to make short work of Goliaths.  When I did this for the achievement, I did it twice in Eridium Blight.  There's a fairly large encampment of bandits up on the hill near Grandma's House.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it and I had a god liath way to high just today he was level 28

Answer (score 0):

From comments at the Reddit - /r/Borderlands post, [**"No... DON'T kill the Goliaths!!"**](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/1i0pk2/no_dont_kill_the_goliaths/) (I added the links to the Borderlands wiki):

> ...I ran into a Loot Goon Goliath at the start of [Hunting the Firehawk](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Hunting_the_Firehawk). I kited him all the way around [Frostburn Canyon](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Frostburn_Canyon), all the way up to the entrance to her lair, letting him kill anything that got in our way.
> ...[Frostburn Canyon](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Frostburn_Canyon) is a great place for kiting them around to level them up. I always get a God-liath going and let him kill Scorch for me.

and

> The best time to make a GOD-liath is the [Slab initiation](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/The_Once_and_Future_Slab). He literally did all the work. Also, in True Vault Hunter, I did a showdown to see who will become the toughest Goliath.
>
> I love the [Once and Future Slab](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/The_Once_and_Future_Slab) mission. I just pop the tops off all the Goliath's then grab some popcorn and settle in for some mayhem.

Answer (score 0):

Best place is at the Firehawk area u get a Goliath there they are immune to fire get a corrosive weapon hurt the bigger guy and he will fame the psycho and spiderling like crazy